# sql server query: how to select customers with more than 1 order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a sql server newbie and trying to select all the customers which have more than 1 orderid. The table looks as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[orders](
    [customerid] [int] NULL,
    [orderid] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[orders] ([customerid], [orderid]) VALUES (1, 2)
INSERT [dbo].[orders] ([customerid], [orderid]) VALUES (1, 3)
INSERT [dbo].[orders] ([customerid], [orderid]) VALUES (2, 4)
INSERT [dbo].[orders] ([customerid], [orderid]) VALUES (2, 5)
INSERT [dbo].[orders] ([customerid], [orderid]) VALUES (3, 1)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
select  customerid
,       count(*) as order_count
from    orders
group by
        customerid
having  count(*) > 1
```

Comment: bedankt voor het snelle antwoord!

Answer (score 4):

as you'll probably need customer data at some point, you could also try:

```
select *
from customers
where exists (
    select count(*)
    from    orders
    where customers.id = customerid
    group by customerid
    having  count(*) > 1
)
```